# Concatenate auto generated strings in java with a space seperator in between

Tags: java, string-concatenation

I have a string array variable which values changes continuously. Random arrays are generated from it. This is what i have:

```
String trans = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata[k], "suggest_text_2");
```

The `trans` value changes continuously. How can i concatenate it with the previous values? How can i print every value of `trans` as it changes continuously? Do i need to use any buffer?

Comment: Think about it, write it, try it and post your question again.

Comment: What did you attempt?

Comment: @Reimeus +1 for a different version for the annoying "*what have you tried*" :P

Comment: i can do normal concatenation .but how can i store the previous value with the new one.

Comment: concatinate a space onto it, and then concatinate the new string

Comment: You should show some effort first. Best I can give is - search for `string concatenation in java`.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do. You want to keep outputting longer and longer strings as new strings are computed? Or do you want to keep outputting just the new value? What does GetColumnValue() do? What have you tried so far? Could you show us an example of the kind of output you're trying to generate?

Comment: @EdwardFalk The getcolumnvalue gets value from database which is a string.ie the string in the column value is assigned to trans.the column value varies and thus the trans value also ,but always limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the intermediate results, you will probably need something like this:

```
String yourOldString;
String freshString;

// other code which updates freshString
yourOldString = yourOldString + " " + freshString;
```

However if you do need to catch all updates but only print out the final result, use a StringBuilder:

```
private static final String WHITESPACE = " ";

String yourOldString;
String freshString;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.append(yourOldString);

// other code which updates freshString
builder.append(WHITESPACE);
builder.append(freshString);

// once everything is done:
String resultString = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thanks marco it works for 5 strings. http://pastebin.com/QVnea95s .As in my example i have 5 strings and the count may vary at times. If the count is varied then it fails.how can it be fixed.i am working on android using this.Do i need to assign null to other values

Answer (score 1):

```
String a = "foo";
String space = " ";
String b = "bar";
String c = a+space+b;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's often best to use StringBuilder to concatenate strings:

```
String [] array { "fee", "fie", "foe", "fum" };

boolean firstTime = true;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
for (String word : array) {
    if (firstTime) {
        firstTime = false;
    } else {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(word);
}

String finalResult = sb.toString();
```

Comment: Instead of firstTime, you can also just check sb.length() > 0. Also, it looks like you got the check backwards. You're only adding a space the first time, instead of adding it every time but the first.

Comment: D'oh! on the check.  Thanks for that.  As for the length check, it'd probably be marginally slower, but far more readible, huh?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("string1 "+"string2");
```

Comment: Before the question was edited my answer was completely relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
String trans = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata[k], "suggest_text_2");
StringBuffer concat = new StringBuffer();
concat.append(test).append(" ");
```

Or,

```
StringBuffer concat = new StringBuffer();
concat.append(Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata[k], "suggest_text_2")).append(" ");
```

To concatenate/combine set of data.

```
for(String s: trans){
  concat.append(s).append(" ");
}
```

`String` concatenation(like `trans + " "`) is slower than the `StringBuffer` `append()`. I strongly suggest you to use `StringBuilder`. Because when combinig `String` on the fly `StringBuffer` is created and then using `toString()` converts to `String`.

Here is nice [blog post to read to learn about performance of these two](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076072/build-ci-sdlc/stringbuffer-versus-string.html).