# Got some issues in Java

Tags: java

I'm still new in Java and I have a problem here. I'm currently learning how to use methods with parameters. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TEST2 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        tuna tunaObject = new tuna ();
        System.out.println("Enter your name here: ");
        String name = input.nextLine(); 
        tunaObject.simpleMessage(name);
    } 
}
```

And another one :

```
public class tuna {
    public void simpleMessage(String name){
    System.out.println("Hello" + name);
    }
}
```

*The problem is, the result is turned out like this:

Enter your name here:

Eddy

HelloEddy

- "HelloEddy" supposed to be "Hello Eddy"
  *Why there's no space? What is the mistake I made in this code, can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: `"Hello" + name = Helloname`. Where did you put your `space`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concatenate auto generated strings in java with a space seperator in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285257/concatenate-auto-generated-strings-in-java-with-a-space-seperator-in-between)

Comment: [Some basic googling](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/combine-two-strings) should be done first before posting, here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a space at the end of the `"Hello"` string, so the line would look like

```
System.out.println("Hello " + name);
```

Take note of the space.

Answer (score 0):

In java Strings are concat by `'+'` symbol or `concat`, to get space in your program you can do something like this:

```
  System.out.println("Hello "+name);
```

or

```
  System.out.println("Hello ".concat(name));
```

Comment: Nobody uses `concat` in this context.

Comment: Yes ... it *could* be used.  But no self-respecting Java program *would* do it.  Experienced Java programmers use the `+` operator ... exclusively.  (Why *would* you choose a form that is both more verbose, and totally unexpected?)